# Java Matcher class not matching a simple pattern

Tags: java, regex

My regex matcher is returning false, and I can't understand why. It works fine on regexr.com

Here's the code:

```
        String test = "Calm_fit calm://listpage?pageid=fitnesstab SomeText";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("/\bcalm?:\/\/\S+/gi");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(test);
        System.out.println("Here 1");

        if (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println("Here 2 Matched: " + matcher.group(1));
        }
```

`Here 2 Matched:`  is not getting printed. Control doesn't enter `if` statement. I'm trying to extract the url `calm://listpage?pageid=fitnesstab` from the text.

Am I missing something here ?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use `Pattern.compile("calm?://\\S+")` and change `if ` to `while`. Java regex is set with string literals, not regex literals, so you can't use `/` delimiters with flags. You will also need to use `matcher.group()`, not `matcher.group(1)`, as the regex contains no capturing groups.

Comment: Java doesn’t use `sed` syntax - please read the docs.

Comment: Also the `\c` would make that not compile at all.

Comment: And there's no `group(1)` in your expression.

Comment: Use `Pattern.compile("calm?://\\S+", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);` and `.group(0)`.

Comment: I'm just looking to find the first match. @RobbyCornelissen so should I use group(0) instead ?

Comment: If you need the first match, why did you add `g` at all? Just keep your `if`, no need of `while`.

Comment: @JoachimSauer missed a `b` there. Edited now.

Comment: Not a big deal, it is `"\\bcalm?://\\S+"` in Java. regex101.com produces the code you can copy/paste into your code, no need to mess with the regex input field text.

Answer (score -1):

To summarize:

- Java regular expressions are defined as strings, not as regex literals. This means that

  - You don't need to delimit your expression using forward slashes.
  - Backslashes need to be escaped.
  - Literal forward slashes don't need to be escaped.
- Flags like `Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE` can be passed as an argument to the [`Pattern.compile()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#compile-java.lang.String-int-) method.
- Your expression has no group 1. Either use group 0 or add additional parentheses to define a group.

Putting it all together:

```
import java.util.regex.*;

public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String test = "Calm_fit calm://listpage?pageid=fitnesstab SomeText";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\bcalm?://\\S+",
                Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(test);

        if (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println(matcher.group(0));
        }
    }
}
```

This produces the following output:

```
calm://listpage?pageid=fitnesstab
```

Comment: I'm just looking to find the first match. So should I just ignore while loop ? I can put it in if statement.

Comment: Yeah, that should be fine, but don't understand why you put a global flag in your expression then.